# How to plot an indexed set of (x,y) pairs such that the index is parallel to the x axis, but on the top of the frame

Tags: r

For example, let say:

```
x <- rnorm(20)

y <- rnorm(20) + 1

n <- seq(1,20,1)

data <- data.frame(n, x, y)
```

Is it possible to plot y~x with the indexed value of each pair at the top of the plot?

Can it be done with the base graphics, not ggplot?

It may be simple, but I am struggling to find help via Google. My guess is I'm using a poor selection of words.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
plot(x,y)
text(x = x, y = y, n, pos = 3)
#Adds text 'n' at co-ordinate (x,y)
# "pos = 3" means the text will be just above the co-ordinates
#See ?text for more
```

If you wanted to plot all the indices on a same line above the plot boundary, you can specify the appropriate value for `y` when using `text`. However, you will first have to pass `par(xpd=TRUE)` to be able to draw outside plot boundary

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can add label. Try this code:

```
x <- rnorm(20)

y <- rnorm(20) + 1

n <- seq(1,20,1)

data <- data.frame(n, x, y)

plot(y~x)

with(data, text(y~x, labels = row.names(data)))
```

[image]